# Url rewriting behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have a simple website with a couple of `.htm` pages, and im trying to use `.htacess` mod rewrite to remove the `.htm` extentions.

I have a folder with 4 `.htm` pages, the index link to the other 3 by href, when I access click the link the url changes from `www.domain.com/` to `www.domain.com/page.htm`, shouldn't it hide the .htm?

Does having url rewriting envolve having each page on a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing this:

use URI's like `www.domain.com/page` in your index file:

and these rules in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.htm [L]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any advantage to use the RewriteCond like you have versus just sticking it in a RewriteRule?

Comment: @dambrisco You can do matches on required parts of the URI or complete URIs without rewriting it. And, in rewriterule, you can: `In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).`

And using RewriteConds will help keep the URl rewriting cleaner(in concern of future rewriterules) and that no conflicts occur..

Comment: @dambrisco Also, `If you wish to match against the full URL-path in a per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule, use the %{REQUEST_URI} variable in a RewriteCond.`

for the above question though does not serve much purpose.

Comment: That clears things up a little bit. It was my understanding that RewriteCond incurred additional processing cost, so I've always tried to avoid it when it wasn't necessary, particularly when matching URIs. I'll definitely read up on this a bit more to give myself a clearer picture. Thanks!